# Saving Entity with Spring MVC and Threads

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, hibernate

Good afternoon, I have a Rest API that is providing services to an android application, to make the service faster I am using threads to save data, for example, I am presenting notifications in the Android application, from the app I am doing a GET and The service is getting the notifications, it also creates a new thread and modifies the "read" attribute from false to true to know that that user has read it. Well, as this conditional change to the application does not affect it to make it faster, I am managing it from a second thread (I only use threads for this, they are very limited and controlled to avoid problems)

It turns out that it is giving me problems xD
When I run the thread and do a create I get an exception and I can't modify the entity

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [com.sbtl.ear.common.entity.impl.NotificationImpl#15] - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:170) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:310) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor.intercept(ByteBuddyInterceptor.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyConfiguration$InterceptorDispatcher.intercept(ProxyConfiguration.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at com.sbtl.ear.common.entity.impl.NotificationImpl$HibernateProxy$OVgkCgyP.merge(Unknown Source) ~[main/:na]
    at com.sbtl.ear.common.kernel.impl.TransactionManagerImpl.createEntity(TransactionManagerImpl.java:156) ~[main/:na]
```

I tell you a little about the code I have
All entities have an implementation of the Merge interface:

```
@Override
    public Object merge(Object parent) {
        if (parent instanceof Notification) {
            Notification notification = (Notification) parent;

            this.title = notification.getTitle();
            this.body = notification.getBody();
            this.opened = notification.isOpened();
            this.action = notification.getAction();
            this.map = notification.getMap();
        }

        return this;
    }
```

The transactions are made from Repository, but I have all those transactions centralized in a single class. So far so good, the exception comes from this special class called TransctionManager (the one that centralizes all the basic operations), it is very simple, from its constructor we put the Repository that we want, this class only has an implementation called JpaRepositoryUser

```
    public TransactionManagerImpl(JpaRepositoryUser<T, Long> jpaRepository, UserRepository userRepository,
                                  ElasticsearchRepository elasticsearchRepository) {
        this.jpaRepository = jpaRepository;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.elasticsearchRepository = elasticsearchRepository;
    }
```

Well, now from the controllers we call the createEntity of this class, what this method does is call the save of the repo, and check that it has to be created from 0 or merge (that's why the implementation of the Merge class), in this way I I make sure that we are going to merge the data we want and those of auditable or non-modifiable are not going to be touched.

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public T createEntity(T entity) throws TransactionalManagerException {
        T entitySaved;
        boolean isCreateMode = entity.getIdentifier() == null;

        try {

            if (isCreateMode) {
                entitySaved = entity;
            } else {
                entitySaved = jpaRepository.getOne((Long) entity.getId());
                entitySaved.merge(entity);
            }

            // em: EntityManager es solo una lista donde tener los datos, hasta que no se
            // realiza el flush no se guarda en base de datos.
            entitySaved = jpaRepository.save(entitySaved);

            if (entitySaved instanceof EntitySearchable) {
                ((EntitySearchable)entitySaved).buildKeywordSearchable();
            }

            if (elasticsearchRepository != null) {
                elasticsearchRepository.save(entitySaved);
            }

            return entitySaved;
        } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
            throw new TransactionalManagerException(e);
        }
    }
```

It turns out that if we call this method from the main thread it works perfectly but if we do it from a second thread it does not work, when the code does `entitySaved = jpaRepository.getOne((Long) entity.getId());` it returns an entity with all its attributes null and when we call merge to merge the data, returns the exception

---

In addition to all this, inform you that this list of Notifications comes from the controller and from a search for elastic (let's say that a double Hibernate get does not come into play)

```
 try {
            Optional<List<Notification>> optionalNotificationList = notificationHandle.searchAllNotificationOfUser(user.getIdentifier());
            if (optionalNotificationList.isPresent()) {
                notifications = optionalNotificationList.get();
                for (Notification notification : optionalNotificationList.get()) {
                    notificationBeans.add(new NotificationBean(notification));
                }
            }

            responseEntity = ResponseEntity.ok(notificationBeans);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            responseEntity = ResponseEntity.badRequest().
                    body(ResponseUtil.exceptionErrorResponse(Notification.class.getName(), e.getMessage()));
        }

        if (notifications != null) {
            WorkThread.Build(1)
                    .addWork(new NotificationRunnable(notifications, notificationHandle))
                    .start();
        }
```

I've seen Hibernate have thread issues, but would there be a way to use Hibernate from another thread seriously?

Comment: You must not share the Hibernate Session or the entities between threads. Altogether they are not thread-safe

Comment: So I have to perform all operations on the main thread and even if the service is slow ?, Is there a way to improve performance when you have multiple entities to update and they are not important for the result?

Comment: One way is to copy the data into objects that are not associated with the Hibernate session, then you can use that data in other threads. Another way is to open one session per thread.